# Parsing missing character in filenames as if is reading / slash character

Tags: string, powershell

Filenames on computer is named like so

```
quant-ph9501001
math9901001
cond-mat0001001
hep-lat0308001
gr-qc0703001
```

but on http links filenames is `/` character included

```
quant-ph/9501001
math/9901001
cond-mat/0001001
hep-lat/0308001
gr-qc/0703001
```

I can't rename my files `quant-ph9501001` into `quant-ph/9501001` because `/` is an illegal character so I can't use my code correctly to parse and rename from *syntax* to *script actions*.

Syntax of my filenames following this pattern:

```
letters + 8 digits
letters + '-' + letters + 8 digits
```

I can change `quant-ph9501001` to `quant-ph_9501001`, but I need to parse missing character in filenames as if reading `/` (slash character).

So if I have strings like

```
gr-qc0701001
gr-qc_0701001
```

it should read like

```
quant-ph/9501001
```

My script don't working (no parsing) for `gr-qc/0701001` because I can't rename filenames using illegal character. Error is 404.

> iwr : The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

If script works correctly PowerShell should be returns this string:

```
General Relativity and Quantum Cosmology (gr-qc)
```

and filename should be

```
Spectral Broadening of Radiation from Relativistic Collapsing Objects
```

My script is

```
    $list1 = @"
quant-ph9802001
quant-ph9802004
"@

$list2 = @"
quant-ph/9802001
quant-ph/9802004
"@

Write-Output "Adding forward slashes"
$list1 -split "`r`n" | % {
    $item = $_.Trim()
    $newItem = $item -replace '(.*)(\d{7})', '$1/$2'
    Write-Output $("{0} ==>  {1}" -f $item, $newItem)
}

Write-Output "Removing forward slashes"
$list2 -split "`r`n" | % {
    $item = $_.Trim()
    $newItem = $item -replace '(.*)/(\d{7})', '$1$2'
    Write-Output $("{0} ==>  {1}" -f $item, $newItem)
}

Function Clean-InvalidFileNameChars {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
      Position=0,
      ValueFromPipeline=$true,
      ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [String]$Name
  )

  $invalidChars = [IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars() -join ''
  $re = "[{0}]" -f [RegEx]::Escape($invalidChars)
  $res=($Name -replace $re)
  return $res.Substring(0, [math]::Min(260, $res.Length))
}

Function Clean-InvalidPathChars {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
      Position=0,
      ValueFromPipeline=$true,
      ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [String]$Name
  )

  $invalidChars = [IO.Path]::GetInvalidPathChars() -join ''
  $re = "[{0}]" -f [RegEx]::Escape($invalidChars)
  $res=($Name -replace $re)
  return $res.Substring(0, [math]::Min(248, $res.Length))
}


$rootpath="c:\temp2"

$rootpathresult="c:\tempresult"

$template=@'
[3]  arXiv:1611.00057 [pdf, ps, other] 
Title: {title*:Holomorphy of adjoint $L$ functions for quasisplit A2} 
Authors: Joseph Hundley 
Comments: 18 pages 
Subjects: {subject:Number Theory (math.NT)} 
[4]  arXiv:1611.00066 [pdf, other] 
Title: {title*:Many Haken Heegaard splittings} 
Authors: Alessandro Sisto 
Comments: 12 pages, 3 figures 
Subjects: {subject:Geometric Topology (math.GT)} 
[5]  arXiv:1611.00067 [pdf, ps, other] 
Title: {title*:Subsumed homoclinic connections and infinitely many coexisting attractors in piecewise-linear maps} 
Authors: David J.W. Simpson, Christopher P. Tuffley 
Subjects: {subject:Dynamical Systems (math.DS)} 
[21]  arXiv:1611.00114 [pdf, ps, other] 
Title: {title*:Faces of highest weight modules and the universal Weyl polyhedron} 
Authors: Gurbir Dhillon, Apoorva Khare 
Comments: We recall preliminaries and results from the companion paper arXiv:1606.09640 
Subjects: {subject:Representation Theory (math.RT)}; Combinatorics (math.CO); Metric Geometry (math.MG)
'@

#extract utils data and clean 
$listbook=gci $rootpath -File -filter *.pdf | foreach { New-Object psobject -Property @{file=$_.fullname; books= ((iwr "https://arxiv.org/abs/$($_.BaseName)").ParsedHtml.body.outerText | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $template)}} | select file -ExpandProperty books |  select file,  @{N="Subject";E={Clean-InvalidPathChars $_.subject}}, @{N="Title";E={Clean-InvalidFileNameChars $_.title}}  

#build dirs and copy+rename file
$listbook | %{$newpath="$rootpathresult\$($_.subject)"; New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "$newpath" -Force;  Copy-Item $_.file "$newpath\$($_.title).pdf" -Force}
```

**EDIT**: Error is still 404 this after Kori Gill answers

https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3jIR.png

Problem is the difference between from local filenames and online filenames. I should add in memory temporally this illegal character in local filenames otherwise script doesn't work.

Comment: To debug, break your complex pipeline statements into pieces.  Using your code on pastebin, there are errors with your ConvertFrom-String.  I did something like: (1) $wr = iwr "https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9802001"; (2) $outer = $wr.ParsedHtml.body.outerHTML; (3) $outer | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $template;

Comment: I don't understand well what you mean. Do you mean replace code like so http://pastebin.com/xPGtdxrH ? But why do you insert a single link like *quant-ph/9802001* ? I have 500+ files to process. Can you show me on pastebin my code edited by you, please ?

Comment: Get it to work for 1 line. Then tackle making it work for 500.  Right now, it seems to break for just 1.

Comment: mm..I wrong something when change with your tips. What is wrong in this edit ? http://pastebin.com/xPGtdxrH. But I should add after `iwr "` something like `"arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9802001";"arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9802002";"arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9802003";` and so on for 500+ filenames ? But code is not too big like so ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't say I totally understand your questions, but sounds like you just need to convert these names to/from a format that has or does not have a forward slash.  You mention 8 digits, but your examples have 7.  You can adjust as needed.

I think something like this will help you...

```
$list1 = @"
quant-ph9501001
math9901001
cond-mat0001001
hep-lat0308001
gr-qc0703001
"@

$list2 = @"
quant-ph/9501001
math/9901001
cond-mat/0001001
hep-lat/0308001
gr-qc/0703001
"@

Write-Output "Adding forward slashes"
$list1 -split "`r`n" | % {
    $item = $_.Trim()
    $newItem = $item -replace '(.*)(\d{7})', '$1/$2'
    Write-Output $("{0} ==>  {1}" -f $item, $newItem)
}

Write-Output "Removing forward slashes"
$list2 -split "`r`n" | % {
    $item = $_.Trim()
    $newItem = $item -replace '(.*)/(\d{7})', '$1$2'
    Write-Output $("{0} ==>  {1}" -f $item, $newItem)
}
```

Outputs:

```
Adding forward slashes
quant-ph9501001 ==>  quant-ph/9501001
math9901001 ==>  math/9901001
cond-mat0001001 ==>  cond-mat/0001001
hep-lat0308001 ==>  hep-lat/0308001
gr-qc0703001 ==>  gr-qc/0703001
Removing forward slashes
quant-ph/9501001 ==>  quant-ph9501001
math/9901001 ==>  math9901001
cond-mat/0001001 ==>  cond-mat0001001
hep-lat/0308001 ==>  hep-lat0308001
gr-qc/0703001 ==>  gr-qc0703001
```